# Limit existing: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Does this limit exist?
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$

I tried some sequnces $(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$, and similar, and limit is $0$. But I can't prove for all. Also, can't prove that there is no limit.

Comment: The subsequential limit of $\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is not zero.

Comment: Try $y=mx$ and see that the limid depends on $m$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n^2}, \frac{1}{n}\right) \rightarrow (0,0)$. If you plug into your formula, you get
$$
\frac{x_n y_n^2}{\left(x_n^2 + y_n^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^4}}{{\left(\frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}} \leq \frac{\frac{1}{n^4}}{\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$
This goes to $0$. However, using $\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)$ like you did gives you $2^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ as the limit:
$$
\frac{x_n y_n^2}{\left(x_n^2 + y_n^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^3}}{{\left(\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^3}}{\left(\frac{2}{n^2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \frac{1}{2^\frac{3}{2}}.
$$
So your function does not have a limit at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
**Method 1: polar coordinates**

Switching to polar coordinates you have:
$$\frac{\rho \cos \vartheta \rho^2 \sin^2 \vartheta }{(\rho^2 \cos^2 \vartheta+\rho^2 \sin^2 \vartheta)^{3/2}}=\frac{\rho^3\cos \vartheta \sin^2 \vartheta}{\rho^3}=\cos \vartheta \sin^2 \vartheta $$
The limit does not exist because the function  depends on $\vartheta$.

**Method 2: restriction $\mathbf{y=x}$**

Considering the path $y=x$ you have:
$$f(x,x)=\frac{x^3}{(2x^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt8} $$
whereas along the path $y=0$ you get $f(x,0)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
Substitute $y=mx$ then you have:
$$ \frac{xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{m^2}{(1+m^2)^{3/2}}$$

You find different limits for different values of $m$ so that the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to considering sequences, you can also use limits along lines that pass through $(0,0)$. For instance,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\y=0} f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{0}{x^3}=0$$
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\y=x} f(x,y) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^3}{(2x^2)^{3/2}} \ne 0$$

If the 2d limit existed, we would get the same result along any path passing through $(0,0)$. Hence, the limit does not exist.